# Synchronizing two different process starting at the same time

Tags: python, unix, cron, synchronization, filesystems

I have a two separate cron services both of which trigger the same python script. I want only one of the invocation to execute and the other one should exit. Is there any way we can achieve this behavior?

Create a lock file based on the process start time (ignoring the seconds part from the timestamp, so that the time becomes unique for both these processes) and touching a file with this name. But this particular approach poses some atomicity issues.

Answer (score 1):

A lock file should be the correct solution, as creating a file only if it does not exist via [touch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.touch) is atomic:

```py
from pathlib import Path

def create_lockfile(filename):
    try:
        Path(filename).touch(exist_ok=False)
        return True
    except FileExistsError:
        return False
```

In the [source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.11/Lib/pathlib.py#L1107) of `touch` you'll find that files are created with the `O_EXCL` flag, meaning the file will only be created if it does not exist yet.

With the atomic issue out of the way, you just need to ensure that all processes try to create the same(!) file, so you can actually use that file as a lock.